# <rich:richtoolTip> in ajax mode and parameters

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm a newbie with JSF so it's really possible that my question is stupid ;-)

I must create a rich:toolTip with "mode=ajax" and I need to send a parameter to my Bean to be able to find the data displayed in the tooltip.

I have tried to do that with  but it's not working.
This is my code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{resultPrestationBean.mainPanelViewOne.data}" id="anId">
  <rich:tooltip mode="ajax" showDelay="250">
    <a4j:actionparam id="test2" value="MyValue" assignTo="#{resultPrestationBean.test2}"/>
    <f:facet name="defaultContent">
      <f:verbatim>Loading...</f:verbatim>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="info #{resultPrestationBean.test}" />
  </rich:tooltip>
</h:outputText>
```

And this is the code in my ResultPrestationBean

```
public String getTest() {
  return "Blabla " + this.test2;
}
public void setTest2(String test2) {
  this.test2 = test2;
}
public void test2(String test2) {
  this.test2 = test2;
}
```

And the result in my tooltip is always "info Blabla null"
If I use the Net panel in Firebug, I see the parameter in the POST...

Could you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can send an actionparam without an action.  I tried this out and was able to get it working by creating a a4j:jsFunction and putting the parameter inside it.  This jsFunction would then be called on the onshow event of the tooltip. BTW, I'm using richfaces 4.

```
<rich:tooltip id="tool1" mode="ajax" showDelay="500" layout="block" followMouse="false" onshow="send();">
    <h:outputText id="tool" value="New Entry #{timesheetHome.rowNum}" />
</rich:tooltip>

<a:jsFunction name="send" render="tool">
    <a:param name="x" value="5" assignTo="#{timesheetHome.rowNum}"></a:param>
</a:jsFunction>
```